# password value does not appear inside textbox on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a non-user model and it has attrs/db-columns, as "password" and there is one more "other password", for both when edited that object, their value do not appear inside textboxes

I did not find any suspicious code inside activeadmin-0.5.1 which would cause this.

Any hints?

Even if I use defaults or put the following, I get the same result

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :user, :as => :select
    f.input :type, :input_html => { :disabled => 'disabled' }
    f.input :password
    f.input :extra
    f.input :other_password
  end
  f.actions
```

end

Seems like some filter on any field being edited having 'password' in its name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to [formtastic's inferred field types](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#the-available-inputs), turning any field matching 'password' to be of type `:password`. Try setting those inputs using the `:as => :string` option:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :user, :as => :select
    f.input :type, :input_html => { :disabled => 'disabled' }
    f.input :password, :as => :string
    f.input :extra
    f.input :other_password, :as => :string
  end
  f.actions
end
```